# Reattaching and manipulating a detached instance in Hibernate (JPA)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, stateless

I use stateless transactional services (meaning, I open a new session and transaction for every call) like this:

```
@Transactional
void someService(Object o) {
    Object newO = entityManager.merge(o);
    newO.getChildren().add(something);
}
```

The Object o which I pass to the service is a **detached object**. The problem with `merge(object)` is, that it returns a **new instance** to manipulate, instead of making the argument itself persistent. So any changes I make on the persistent object are not happening to the original object in memory.

I could of course rewire all my local references, but I am hoping there is a better solution.

Is there a way to make my local instance *managed*, instead of getting a new instance?

I tried `refresh(object)` and `update(object)` but I do get exceptions because the associations of the object are still detached.

When I annotate the associations with `@Cascade(value=CascadeType.save-update)` it works fine, but doesn't that cause performance issues when I have a lot of OneToMany or ManyToMany associations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use the detached `Object o` and after just to use the `session.update(o)`.

Try to watch [this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T02FicxK_aY&list=PL4AFF701184976B25), maybe it will be useful!

Ciao!

Comment: +1 thx for the link. for some reason it doesn't work properly for me though. I'll review and post once I got to the bottom of this.

Comment: I got it. I should have mentioned that I am manipulating associations while the object is detached. all manipulated associations seem to need the cascade=save-update annoatation or he complains about them not being attached during the update call

Comment: Good! Useful to know!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [find(entityClass, primaryKey)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29) method to load your object. Just specify the primary key and the entity Class values and it returns a live object from the DB.

Now make your changes to this object and any changes made to this live object, will be reflected back and hibernate will update the database accordingly. I've personally faced such a situation and this worked for me.

Comment: I have a local object in memory, which is detached. How do I make this local instance managed? find() will return me a new instance as well.

Comment: Once done with the changes, you can `persist()` that object and the changes will be reflected.